# Ajax request not passing changed strings to JsonResult parameters?

Tags: json, ajax, asp.net-core

I'm attempting to pass the values of two elements through an Ajax call to my JsonResult parameters every time the values change, but it isn't picking up the new values (stays as the old values).

My html and javasript:

```html
<select class="form-control" id="selspecialist" asp-for="SelSpecialist" asp-items="Model.SpecialistList"></select>
<select class="form-control" id="selreqtype" asp-for="SelReqType" asp-items="Model.ReqTypeList"></select>
```

```js
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#mytable').DataTable({
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            ajax: {
                url: "?handler=loadListJson" + "&selSpecialist=" + document.getElementById("selspecialist").value
                        + "&selReqType=" + document.getElementById("selreqtype").value,
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("RequestVerificationToken",
                        $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
                },
            },
            columns: [
                { data: "part" },
                { data: "requestTo" },
                { data: "subGroup" },
                { data: "dueDt", type: 'date' },
                { data: "desc" },
                { data: "reason" },
                { data: "reqType" },
                { data: "lastUpdateDt", visible: false },
                {
                    data: null,
                    render: function (data, type, row) {
                        return "<a href='#' class='btn btn-primary btn-xs' onclick=LoadPartUpdate('" + row.part + "'); ><i class='fa fa-edit' aria-hidden='true' style='color:#ffffff; font-size:13px;'></i></a>";
                    }
                }
            ]
        });
        $('#selspecialist').on('change', function () { $('#mytable').DataTable().draw(); });
        $('#selreqtype').on('change', function () { $('#mytable').DataTable().draw(); });
    });
```

My JsonResult method:

```cs
public JsonResult OnPostLoadListJson(string selSpecialist, string selReqType)
        {
            vwOpenRequests = _context.vwOpenRequests.OrderBy(x => x.Sort);
            if (selSpecialist != null) { vwOpenRequests = vwOpenRequests.Where(s => s.RequestTo.Contains(selSpecialist)); }
            if (selReqType != null) { vwOpenRequests = vwOpenRequests.Where(s => s.ReqType.Contains(selReqType)); }
            return new JsonResult(new { data = vwOpenRequests });
        }
```

Comment: Hi , you are passing values in url ? isn't that be `get` request ?

Comment: @Swati true, but I couldn't get "data" option in ajax to pass my values at all (they were always null) and found that this worked instead, which is why.

Answer (score 1):

Modify the onchange event, you should reload the datatable with new parameters like this:

```
$('#selspecialist').on('change', function () {
    $('#mytable').DataTable().ajax.url("?handler=loadListJson" + "&selSpecialist=" + document.getElementById("selspecialist").value
        + "&selReqType=" + document.getElementById("selreqtype").value).load();
});
$('#selreqtype').on('change', function () {
    $('#mytable').DataTable().ajax.url("?handler=loadListJson" + "&selSpecialist=" + document.getElementById("selspecialist").value
        + "&selReqType=" + document.getElementById("selreqtype").value).load();
});
```